# Cannot import ManagedObject class

Tags: swift, core-data

it's a most stupid question I asked here, but after few fours of trying i have the same answer from Xcode — ”No such module”.
I made a model. I made a simple UX. Everything works.
I subclassed NSManagedObjects from data model: Location and AxisValues.
I've got four files:

```
AxisValues.swift
AxisValues+CoreDataProperties.swift
Location.swift
Location+CoreDataProperties.swift
```

They looks very nice. They have correct target membership. 
And now I try to import classes to Document.swift:

```
import Location
import AxisValues
```

Nope. Computer says ”No such module”.
I repeated this task few times, cleaned product... WTF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift all files in the current workspace including all symbols are imported automatically.

Just delete the `import` lines